# How to get filename of all attachements of email?

Tags: java, imap, attachment

I am trying to get the filename of all the attachements of emails using java and imap.My code is:

```
MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage) messages[i];
String fileName = msg.getFileName();
System.out.println("The file name of this attachment is " + fileName);
```

but it prints null always even if email contain attachment..I have seen different codes on SO but none worked...and I don't know what to do if attachment is more than one .
PS:I only want to get the filename and don't want to download attachments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, to determine if a message may contain attachments using the following code:

```
// suppose 'message' is an object of type Message
String contentType = message.getContentType();

if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
    // this message may contain attachment
}
```

Then we must iterate through each part in the multipart to identify which part contains the attachment, as follows:

```
Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();

for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
    if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
        // this part is attachment
        // code to save attachment...
    }
}
```

And to save the file, you could do:

```
part.saveFile("D:/Attachment/" + part.getFileName());
```

[Source](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/download-attachments-in-e-mail-messages-using-javamail)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue when the email contained another email as an attachment. The content-disposition of such an attachment does not contain fileName.

```
String contentType = message.getContentType(); 
List<String> attachmentFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
if(contentType.contains("multipart"))
    {
        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart)message.getContent(); 
        int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount(); 
        for(int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++)
        {
            MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart)multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount); 
            if(Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                String fileName = part.getFileName();
                String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
                //If the attachment is an email, fileName will be null.
                if ("message/rfc822".equalsIgnoreCase(part.getContentType())) {
                    MimeMessage tempMessage = new MimeMessage(null, part.getInputStream());
                    fileName = tempMessage.getSubject()+".eml"; //all the email attachments will be converted to .eml format.
                    extension = "eml";
                }
                File tempEmailFile = File.createTempFile(messageId + "_" + partCount , "." + extension);
                part.saveFile(tempEmailFile); 
                attachmentFiles.add(fileName);
                attachmentFiles.add(tempEmailFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Reference: [javamail also extract attachments of encapsulated message Content-Type: message/rfc822](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38874376/)

Answer (score 2):

there is an easier way with apache commons mail:

```
final MimeMessageParser mimeParser = new MimeMessageParser(mimeMessage).parse();
final List<DataSource> attachmentList = mimeParser.getAttachmentList();
for (DataSource dataSource: attachmentList) {
            final String fileName = dataSource.getName();
            System.out.println("filename: " + fileName);
}
```

Comment: The problem with using this is that it will get the content as a byte[] and load attachments in to memory. This is inefficient if all you need is to determine if there's attachments or read attachment file names.